# Sonar-Scanner for Ant issue

Tags: ant, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am currently working changing an build.xml file that was supported by sonar-ant-task 1.4 to build.xml for SonarQube Scanner for Ant 2.5 facing issues related to nomenclature. SonarQube 5.6.3.
    We created a custom plugin for salesforce language custom plugin for older version upgrading it to the latest one. Build.xml is as below

`

```
      <!-- Define the Sonar task -->
      <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="sonar-ant-task-2.5.jar" />
      </taskdef>

      <!-- define the force versions task -->
        <taskdef name='scm' classname='com.villagechief.codescan.versions.ant.ScmCommitterTask'>
        <classpath path="force-versions-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
      </taskdef>

      <!-- Define the Salesforce task -->
      <taskdef uri="salesforce" resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="ant-salesforce.jar" />
      </taskdef>
       <!-- Add the target -->
      <target name="sonar">
      <!--java srcdir="sonar-project-template\src" target="sonar-project-template\src" bootclasspath="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_145\jre\lib\rt.jar"/-->
         <property name="sonar.host.url" value="Link to another server/" />

        <property Name="sonar.login" value="****"/>
        <property Name="sonar.password" value="****"/>

        <!-- db properties -->
        <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://<serverip>;databaseName=sonar" />
        <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="****" />
        <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="****" />


        <!-- location properties -->
        <property name="sonar.sources" value="${user.dir}/src" />
        <property name="sonar.binaries" value="${user.dir}/bin" />
        <property name="sonar.tests" value="${user.dir}/tests" />
        <property name="sonar.libraries" value="${user.dir}/" />

        <!-- define if not already defined properties -->
        <property name="sonar.language" value="sf" />
        <property name="salesforce.url" value="https://www.salesforce.com" />
        <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0-SNAPSHOT" />
        <sonar:sonar key="${sonar.projectKey}" version="${sonar.projectVersion}" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>
      </target>

      <target name="commit">
        <scm username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" repository="${scm}" >
                <fileset dir="${user.dir}/src">
                    <include name="**/*"/>
                </fileset>
            </scm>
      </target>

      <target name="deletesrc">
        <delete dir="${user.dir}/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
            <exclude name="package.xml"/>
        </delete>

      </target>
      <target name="download">
        <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
        <sf:retrieve username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" 
          retrieveTarget="src" unpackaged="src/package.xml"/>
        <!--   
        <sf:retrieve username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" 
          retrieveTarget="src" packageNames=""/>-->
      </target>

      <target name="deploy">
        <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
        <sf:deploy username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" 
          deployroot="src"/>
      </target>

      <target name="commitall">
        <exec executable="git" dir="${user.dir}">
          <arg value="add"/>
          <arg value="-A"/>
        </exec>
        <exec executable="git" dir="${user.dir}">
          <arg value="commit"/>
          <arg value="-a"/>
          <arg value="-m"/>
          <arg value="&lt;automcommit: all&gt;"/>
        </exec>
      </target>
      <!-- <target name="analyse" depends="deletesrc, download, commit, commitall, sonar" /> -->
      <!--target name="analyse" depends="deletesrc, download, sonar" /-->
    <target name="analyse" depends=" download, sonar" />
    </project>
    `
```

Please let me know where am i getting it wrong. The issue is when I run the command : #!/bin/sh ant -f ../build.xml analyse
The analyse is not being sent to the server it shows to be executing properly in the logs. So i think there is something wrong with the build.xml. So I need help.

This is the log that i get after running the command : ant -f build.xml analyse

```
Buildfile: C:\runner\runner\antbuild.xml

deletesrc:

download:
[sf:retrieve] Request for a retrieve submitted successfully.
[sf:retrieve] Request Id for the current retrieve task: 04s90000003elivAAA
[sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Completed
[sf:retrieve] Finished request 04s90000003elivAAA successfully.

sonar:

analyse:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 15 seconds
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I _know_ you didn't just post your analysis credentials on StackOverflow. I've nonetheless *-ed them out. However, people with enough rep can still see them in the edit history. So on the off chance that you hadn't had your coffee when you posted this, you should update your credentials NOW.

Comment: Also, you don't actually state what the problem is

Comment: How do you know the analysis result isn't being sent to your server? Errors in the analysis log? Something else? Also, please [edit] your question to include your version of SonarQube

Comment: There are no errors in the analysis log and i cant see anything in the back ground tasks

Comment: It might be helpful to [edit] your question to include some or all of the analysis log

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's swallowing your errors, but when I ran with a chopped-down version of your `build.xml`, I got:

```
sonar:sonar doesn't support the "key" attribute
```

In fact, the `sonar:sonar` tag doesn't support *any* attributes. So okay. Remove all the attributes and try again:

```
You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey
```

So add

```
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="foo"/>
```

And analysis runs beautifully.

That said, I made some other changes to the task that I haven't mentioned yet. First, assuming a modern version (>5.2) of SonarQube, there's no need to provide database credentials to the analysis, so that should be stripped out. Second, from 5.3, you shouldn't be providing SonarQube login and password, but [generating a token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) and passing it as the login value. And finally, `sonar.binaries` is long-since deprecated. Use `sonar.java.binaries` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for further insight into Build.xml ant execution. I have made the changes as you have asked. but we need to make the property key as a variable. Even if i fix that issue by fixing the property i get the following issue
Moreover it throws :\runner\runner\build.xml:86: The prefix "sonar" for element "sonar:sonar" is not bound. issue in the build.xml. which can be resolved by adding xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" into project I already have 
<project name="VillageChief DataHub" xmlns:sf="salesforce">
  so need to get it there i am trying to find the solution